# Bar chart stacked vertically using Image-Charts

Tags: image-charts

I have started using the [Image-Charts Docs for Bar Charts](https://documentation.image-charts.com/bar-charts/)

Vertically grouped Bars chart works as expected. You can see all 3 Items grouped(see the image below).

[image: Vertically grouped bars]

But

Using the same data in url for a Vertically stacked shows only 2 Items stacked (see the example from the docs below).
**Both images attached can be found in the link to documentation**

[image: Vertically Stacked, only 2 Items stacked]

I work with this url to output stacked bar chart, but some Items are not visible/displayed.

```
https://image-charts.com/chart?cht=bvs&chs=800x725&chd=a:0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5882,9662,9363,9320,9363|0,0,0,0,0,0,500,3000,2520,6453,5000,3658|0,0,0,3358,0,0,0,7960,3040,584,601,2800|0,0,0,10488,0,0,0,1011,1659,290,4017,0|0,0,0,1050,1050,1050,1155,1050,1480,1150,1150,1150|0,0,0,0,0,0,0,623,1935,188,6796,404|0,0,0,0,0,0,0,833,833,833,833,833|0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,819,819,819,0|0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1300|0,0,0,0,0,0,0,110,440,0,489,111|0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,199,5,0|0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,29,34,82,29|0,0,0,0,0,0,0,32,32,32,28,36|0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,81|0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,11|0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,0&chco=648b7b,00e08a,00158b,8b0056,8b0000,a7f74a,ff9d00,ed0000,aa5555,555faa,202d91,18d4e3,d05bc7,9a5bd0,8d881a,8d5c1a&chxl=0:|Oct2017|Nov2017|Dec2017|Jan2018|Feb2018|Mar2018|Apr2018|May2018|Jun2018|Jul2018|Aug2018|Sep2018|&chg=10,30&chdl=Results$|Results|Results$|Results|Results$|Results|Results$|Results|Results$|Results|Results$|Results|Results$|Results|Results$|Results&chxt=x,y&chma=20,50,20&chtt=Vertically-stacked+Bar+Chart`
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your report, there was indeed an issue with our `bvs` support, it's now fixed:

[image: chart]